# How can I find a element that has a particular name attribute using ElementTree in Python

Tags: python, elementtree

I'm using ElementTree and have a list of names whose elements I'd like to find in Python.

I have a list names

```
namelist = ['jenna', 'bob', 'sue']
```

For each of these names I'd like to find their entire element and write it to a file.
The format of my file is such that

```
<fistnames>
<firtname name = 'jenna'>
...
</firstname>
</firstnames>
```

Then I tried the following to find the firstname element that corresponds to the list.

```
for eachfirstname in namelist:
    firstnames = library.find('firstnames')
    **firstname = firstnames.find('firstname', @name=firstname)**
```

This didn't work... What is the proper syntax to find an element based on an attribute's value -- in this case `name`?

Comment: http://effbot.org/zone/element-xpath.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use xpath expressions for that:

```
for name in namelist:
    firstname = library.find('.//firstname[@name="{}"]'.format(name))
```

Comment: Just tried this... I get `NameError: global name 'name' is not defined`

Comment: @user1328021: Note that my loop uses `for name ...`.

Comment: Oops.. ok now I'm getting `SyntaxError: invalid predicate`

Comment: @user1328021: Yes, I corrected my answer to fix the missing `"` quotes, make sure you have those. :-)

Comment: Thanks Martijn! I actually have never seen the syntax `[@name="{}"]'.format(name))` in particular the `{}` to reference the item in a for loop. Is that across all of python that you can do this? And if yes, does it always have to follow with `.format(loopitem)` ?

Comment: @user1328021: The `{}` is a formatting placeholder; see the [`str.format()` method](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format). You can use this on any string object, and not just with loop variables.